# Selendroid Python ActivityNotFound Exception

Tags: python, selenium, android-activity, selendroid

I am learning how to use selendroid to automate mobile apps in Python.

I followed http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html and was successful in getting the mobile web simulation to work.

But I am having problems getting the native app example to work http://selendroid.io/native.html.

My goal is to be able to test the instagram application.

These are the steps i followed:

1. I downloaded the instagram apk file from
   http://www16.zippyshare.com/d/ItozZOlJ/28269/com.instagram.android-7.9.2-APK4Fun.com.apk and installed it on a BlueStacks emulator
2. Next i start the selenium standalone server with the apk file as the app parameter

   ```
    java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar -aut H:\PDS\andriod\com.instagram.android-7.9.2-APK4Fun.com.apk
   ```
3. To verify if everything was loaded fine I checked the link http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status and got :

   ```
   {
       status: 0,
       value: {
       supportedApps: [
           {
               appId: "io.selendroid.androiddriver:0.17.0",
               mainActivity: "io.selendroid.androiddriver.WebViewActivity",
               basePackage: "io.selendroid.androiddriver"
           },
           {
               appId: "com.instagram.android:7.9.2",
               mainActivity: "com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity",
               basePackage: "com.instagram.android"
           }
       ],
       os: {
           arch: "amd64",
           name: "Windows 8.1",
           version: "6.3"
       },
       build: {
           browserName: "selendroid",
           version: "0.17.0"
       },
       supportedDevices: [
           {
               platformVersion: "23",
               emulator: true,
               apiTargetType: "google",
               avdName: "Nexus_5_API_23_x86"
           }
       ]
       }
   }
   ```

   That should mean everything is good. I have my device recognized, and the apk file was loaded with the MainActivity identified.
4. Now I write the script to be able to start the instagram app

   ```
   # initiate the driver
   driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.ANDROID)

   # switch to native app 
   driver.switch_to.window("NATIVE_APP")
   try:
       # try to start the MainTabActivity
       driver.get("and-activity://com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity")
   finally:
       driver.quit()
   ```

   When i execute the script i get the following error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "F:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2403, in <module>
       globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
     File "F:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1794, in run
       launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
     File "H:/PDS/BNP/bots/xexamples/connect_to_phone.py", line 12, in <module>
       driver.get("and-activity://com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity")
     File "H:\program files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 213, in get
       self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
     File "H:\program files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
     File "H:\program files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: CATCH_ALL: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {io.selendroid.androiddriver/com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1723)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1511)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1039)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1021)
       at io.selendroid.server.ServerInstrumentation.startActivity(ServerInstrumentation.java:77)
       at io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidNativeDriver.get(SelendroidNativeDriver.java:115)
       at io.selendroid.server.model.DefaultSelendroidDriver.get(DefaultSelendroidDriver.java:522)
       at io.selendroid.server.handler.OpenUrl.safeHandle(OpenUrl.java:38)
       at io.selendroid.server.handler.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:86)
       at io.selendroid.server.AndroidServlet.handleRequest(AndroidServlet.java:264)
       at io.selendroid.server.common.BaseServlet.handleHttpRequest(BaseServlet.java:67)
       at io.selendroid.server.common.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:53)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
       at io.netty.handler.traffic.AbstractTrafficShapingHandler.channelRead(AbstractTrafficShapingHandler.java:223)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
       at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:148)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:430)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:384)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
   ```

   It throws the ActivityNotFoundException error, and asks if i have declared this activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

**Questions :**

- How do I check if something is declared in the AndroidManifest?
- If something is not declared, how do i declare it? (shouldn't installing an app automatically put it in the Android Manifest?)
- Am i doing something wrong in the script?
- Can using bluestacks be somehow related to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check what's in the AndroidManifest by using the `apktool`. The main activity is also specified in the selendroid server log, right when you start it.
2. You could probably do that if you decompile the app, add it into the AndroidManifest and compile it back. This probably won't help you, because even if you'll add a new activity in the manifest, your app won't use that activity, unless the code is written to do that.
3. Not really
4. Not as far as I know

I am having the same exact problem

The problem can be seen here:

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {io.selendroid.androiddriver/com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Selendroid tries to use the activity, located in the *default* app that selenium server has instead of the one you passed with the *app* argument. Which is the *io.selendroid.androiddriver*. Might be a bug

Looking for a solution though